# php laravel return all data from foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am trying to get data from db into a single array

This what i have edit he Code Thanks Matt C

```
foreach ($list1 as &$day){
           $pleads = \DB::table('leads')
            ->selectRaw('count(*)') 
            ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id')
            ->where('lead_source_id', 7)
            ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");

            $mleads = \DB::table('leads')
                    ->selectRaw('count(*)')
                    ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id')
                    ->where('lead_source_id', 3)
                    ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");

            $aleads = \DB::table('leads')
                    ->selectRaw('count(*)')
                    ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id')
                    ->where('lead_source_id', 4)
                    ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");

            $personalleads = \DB::table('users') 
                    ->where('id', $id) // User ID
                    ->select('users.id')
                    ->selectSub($pleads, 'pleads')
                    ->selectSub($mleads, 'mleads')
                    ->selectSub($aleads, 'aleads')
                    ->get();
                    return $personalleads;
                     }
```

when i do this i get only 1 output ex:

```
[{"userid":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":1,"aleads":1}]
```

but what i want as result is below

```
[{"userid":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":1,"aleads":1},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0}]
```

`print_r` of what i get

```
( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 1 [pleads] => 2 [mleads] => 1 [aleads] => 1 ) ) )  ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 1 [pleads] => 0 [mleads] => 0 [aleads] => 0  ) ) )  ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 1 [pleads] => 0 [mleads] => 0 [aleads] => 0  ) ) ) ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 1 [pleads] => 1 [mleads] => 0 [aleads] => 0  ) ) )  ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 1 [pleads] => 1 [mleads] => 0 [aleads] => 0  ) ) )  ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 1 [pleads] => 1 [mleads] => 0 [aleads] => 0  ) ) )  ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 1 [pleads] => 0 [mleads] => 0 [aleads] => 0  ) ) )
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You're not using `$day` anywhere. You're just getting the exact same data over and over again and putting it in the same place

Comment: What is your print_r value ?

Comment: sorry re edited. 
> it's posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using Eloquent relationships and reusing your code you should be able to get the counts using selectSub.

```
$pleads = \DB::table('leads')
            ->selectRaw('count(*)') 
            ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id)
            ->where('lead_source_id', 7)
            ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");

$mleads = DB::table('leads')
        ->selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id)
        ->where('lead_source_id', 3)
        ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");

$aleads = \DB::table('leads')
        ->selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id)
        ->where('lead_source_id', 4)
        ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");


$personalleads = \DB::table('user')         
        ->select('users.id')
        ->selectSub($pleads, 'pleads')
        ->selectSub($mleads, 'mleads')
        ->selectSub($aleads, 'aleads')
        ->get()
```

You should get back something like this for each user.

```
[{"id":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":1,"aleads":1}]
```

There are many ways to do this though

With Eloquent Relationships

```
User::withCount([
        'leads as pleads' => function ($q) {
            $q->where('lead_source_id', 7)
                ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");
        },
        'leads as mleads' => function ($q) {
            $q->where('lead_source_id', 3)
                ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");
        },
        'leads as aleads' => function ($q) {
            $q->where('lead_source_id', 4)
                ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");
        },
    ])
    ->first()
    ->only(['id', 'pleads','mleads', 'aleads'])
```

Comment: First i would like to thank you very much for your answer i have been looking everywhere for someone to help me on this task 
i got ``[{"id":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":1,"aleads":1}]``
  but this code is inside foreach i want to return 
``[{"userid":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":1,"aleads":1},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0}]`` instead of just 1 line

Comment: Many thanks i would really appreciate it if you helped me with the foreach loop problem cuz i have been trying to solve it for 8 hours straight but with no luck

Comment: Should work without the foreach now and return all users.

Comment: thank you but the problem is that i have to use the foreach because i want to retrive the data from db by each day of the last month and when i use the return inside the foreach it returns only the 1st day i will edit the post

Comment: Can you post that part of the code? This portion only loops through each user.

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: The            foreach ($list1 as &$day){
} is what loop through the days and execute the block of code each day of the past month to get the data according to each day of the past month but the problem i get only 1 day in return

Comment: You can just use a temporary array to store it in. Before loop `$days = []` in loop `$days []= $personalleads`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190565/discussion-between-mohamed-adel-and-matt-c).